# (Python) Update background via radio button python

Tags: python, tkinter, self

So I am trying to change the background of this frame when a certain radiobutton is selected.

My frame is in a class and the functions for the radiobuttons or outside of this class. (This is so I can call them on all the other frames.)

The problem is that i get the following error whenever I select a radiobutton:

```
configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

However, when placing `self` inside or `configure`, it says that `self` is not defined.

I'm not 100% on when to use `self` so any help would be apprectiated.

The functions for changing the background:

```
def bgLight():
    Options.configure(self, bg="#fff")
    Options.configure(self, fg="#000")

def bgDark():
    Options.configure(bg="#000")
    Options.configure(fg="#fff")
```

And the code for the radio buttons:

```
class Options(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    label = tk.Label(self, text="Options", font=TITLE_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Change it up a bit!", font=SUBTITLE_FONT)
    label.pack(fill="x", pady=10)

    #These are the two radio buttons that will change the background color
    radio = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="One", value=1, command=bgLight)
    radio.pack()
    radio = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Two", value=0, command=bgDark)
    radio.pack()

    button = tk.Button(self, text="Back To Main Menu",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Menu"))
    button.pack()
```

Like I said, I'm not 100% confident on when or where to use `self` so I have mainly been experimenting on where to put it.

Comment: what is `Menu` exactly, a variable referring to some instance ?

Comment: @PRMoureu It was another frame that I was working on! I have swapped it to Options which is the one I want to change, but I get the same errors.

Comment: But you want to apply the new background to the Option Frame or another one ? is it stored in the controler maybe ?

Comment: @PRMoureu I want to apply the new background to all of the frames, but I mainly focused on the Options frame for now. The two functions are stored at the very beginning of the program, just after the imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `configure` needs to be applied to instances, not to the base class.

To make it work at the `Options` class level, you can declare the functions `bgLight` and `bgDark` as methods of the class :

```
def bgLight(self):
    self.configure(bg="#fff")
    #self.configure(fg="#000") no foreground on Frame

def bgDark(self):
    self.configure(bg="#000")
    #self.configure(fg="#fff")
```

Don't forget to change the calls in `Radiobutton` commands :

```
radio = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="One", value=1, command=self.bgLight)
radio = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Two", value=0, command=self.bgDark)
```

---

A way to handle this at the application level could be to define an attribute `background` and `foreground` in the `controler` , then call the method `configure` when you need, by giving the parameter from `controler`.
Careful, some widgets don't have a foreground attribute, like `tkinter.Frame`.

In `Options`, the methods could be :

```
def bgLight(self):
    self.controller.background = "#fff"
    self.controller.foreground = "#000"

def bgDark(self):
    self.controller.background = "#000"
    self.controller.foreground = "#fff"
```

Comment: So if I wanted to put this across all the frames that I have across my application, where would I define these attributes? In each individual frame, or the frame controller? And how you I change the background of the other widgets in the same frame?

Comment: i didn't see the class so i can't tell if it's easier to use the controller. It looks to be the top level class, and always living,  so the best to store this kind of parameter. now the difficulty is to refresh the existing widgets, do you already store them in the controller ? Another option : Are you using a file to store the configuration ?

Comment: No I just have the one file, and I call each frame to be the top level. Here is a pastebin link for the entire code(if it helps): https://pastebin.com/WGFb6ciY Im not quite sure what you mean by controller.